# in postgres, is it possible to optimize a VIEW of UNIONs

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, query-optimization

in the database there are many identical schemas, `cmp01`..`cmpa0`

each schema has a `users` table

each schema's `users` table's primary key has its own unique range

for example, in `cmp01.users` the `usr_id` is between `0x01000000 and 0x01ffffffff`.

is there any way I could define a VIEW `global.users` that is a union of each of the `cmp*.union` tables in such a way that, if querying by `usr_id`, the optimizer would head for the correct schema?

was thinking something like:

```
create view global.users as
select * from cmp01.users where usr_id between 0x01000000 and 0x01ffffffff
union all
select * from cmp02.users where usr_id between 0x02000000 and 0x02ffffffff
....
```

would this work?  NO.  EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows all schema used.

Is there an approach that might give good hints to the optimizer?

Comment: What's the data type of `usr_id`?

Comment: According to your description, the WHERE clauses in your query are redundant. You put them there anyway as hint for the query planer, correct? Might work, just test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  re EXPLAIN ANALYZE - good idea.  need to insert some dummy data and give it a whirl.  will take a while.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - no joy.  EXPLAIN ANALYZE goes through each of the schema in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a partitioned table? The master table would be created as `global.users` and it would be partitioned by the schema name.

That way you'd get the small user tables in each schema (including fast retrievals) provided you can create queries that PostgreSQL can optimize i.e. including the schema name in the where condition. You could also create a view in each schema that would hide the needed schema name to query the partitioned tables. I don't think it would work by specifying only the user_id. I fear that PostgreSQL's partitioning features are not smart enough for that.

Or use just one single table, and create views in each schema with an instead of trigger and limiting the result to that schema's users.

Comment: this sounds promising.  will give it a shot.

Comment: the more I look at partitioning the schemas the better I like it.  really like using schema to segregate users. still have problems with optimization.  aesthetically more pleasing - essentially having the view created by virtue of the ancestor table.

Answer (score 3):

Why not create a table in a public schema that has all users in it, possibly with an extra column to store the source schema. Since the ids are globally unique, you could keep the id column unique:

```
create table all_users (
source_schema varchar(32),
usr_id int primary key,
-- other columns as per existing table(s)
);
```

Poluate the table by inserting all rows:

```
insert into all_users
select 'cmp01', * from cmp01.users union
select 'cmp02', * from cmp02.users union ...; -- etc
```

Use triggers to keep the table up to date.

It's not that hard to set up, and it will perform every well

Comment: true.  best idea yet.  two problems: 1) normalization, 2) many updates to users table that would be triggered.  big advantage: much faster for normal query since, for example, one index for `email`, not 152 indexes.

Comment: seems like what we're really after is something like Oracle's materialized view.  don't think pg goes anywhere in that direction - where views are instantiated into tables on demand.

Comment: @ccyoung: you can simulate Oracle's MVIEW using triggers and a cron job. For a possible solution have a look here: http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views and here: http://www.pgcon.org/2008/schedule/events/69.en.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - very nice links, thanks.  since all the dml is through stored procedures this would be a pretty pie to slice.

Comment: @ccyoung: You say "two problems: 1) normalization,..." This design is indeed normalized. One table of users instead of the 150 ones you have. Why is that a problem?

Comment: perhaps I missed what you were saying.  thought we were talking about keeping user info in each schema and then copying out to global schema using triggers.  from my perspective, having two copies of the same data is non-normal.  cannot have global.users as sole copy - the schema enforce security in the db, ie, ordinary users are always constrained within their schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
create view global.users as
select *
from (select 'cmp01' sel_schema, 0x01000000 usr_id_start, 0x01ffffffff usr_id_end
      union all
      select 'cmp02' sel_schema, 0x02000000 usr_id_start, 0x02ffffffff usr_id_end) s
join (select u1.*, 'cmp01' schema from cmp01.users u1
      union all
      select u2.*, 'cmp02' schema from cmp02.users u2) u
on s.sel_schema = u.schema
```

and include a condition like `specified_usr_id between usr_id_start and usr_id_end` when querying the view by a specified user ID.

Comment: maybe so!  will test, but will take a while.